# getting values from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, it can have any state at this point in the program (empty or with some other arrays that have been inserted with this format).

```
$productName=$_POST['productname'];
if(!in_array($productName,$productArray)) {
    $productArray[]=array($productName,$_POST['price'],$_POST['desc']);
}
```

(It gets the values correctly from a form, I checked that)

And basically, what I want to do is to add an array to the array so that I have a multidimensional array. (I know not the most beautiful solution, but hey)
My browser does not give an error, so I think that is fine, but when I am trying to put it out, it does not give back anything.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($productArray);$i++) {
    echo "Name: ",$productArray[i][0],"<br>";
    echo "Price: ",$productArray[i][1],"<br>";
    echo "Description: ",$productArray[i][2],"<br>";
```

}

My website does not put out anything it all, it just says "Name: " and then nothing.
What have I done wrong? (I am just starting to learn PHP, maybe I am missing something obvious)

Comment: `$productArray[i][0]` => `$productArray[$i][0]` . Set `display_errors` to `On`. Your `in_array()` test is wrong (since you search a string in an array that only contains array items).

Comment: it's just typo in echo command. replace commas with dots: it should be `echo "Name: " . $productArray[i][0] . "<br>";`

Comment: @Banzay: No, commas are correct and avoid useless concatenations with the `echo` command (see `echo` in [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php))

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte , didn't know that!  Thank you for the tip, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

$productArray[i][0] => $productArray[$i][0] . Set display_errors to On. Your in_array() test is wrong (since you search a string in an array that only contains array items).

The guy commenting answered it, I had this stupid oversight. Thanks a lot! :)